# Mocking @Resource when using MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockmvc

My team is currently building a SpringBoot API. Below is a snippet of how my team is mocking for our controller tests. This works when we have plain classes as dependencies.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestController {

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Mock
    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private MyController myController;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

        //Build the controller mock handler
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .standaloneSetup(myController)
            .build();
    }
```

We cannot figure out how to mock a @Resource like below for a similar test.

```
@Resource(name = "domainNameToCode")
private Map<String, Integer> domainCodes;
```

Comment: You're supposed to pass the controller **instance** to `standaloneSetup()`, not the controller class.

Comment: Apologies...just a typo. Fixed post.

Comment: Annotate a setter with @Resource instead of annotating the private field, and call that setter to set the map. You can probably also use `@Spy private Map<...> domainCodes = createDomainCodes();` in your test

Answer (score 0):

As the `domainCodes` is private your controller needs to have a way to set value for it either constructor or a setter.

**Setter**

```
    @Autowired()
    @Qualifier("domainNameToCode")
    public void setDomainCodes(Map<String, Integer> domainCodes) {
        ...
    }
```

**Constructor**

```
  @Autowired()
    @Qualifier("domainNameToCode")
    public MyController(Map<String, Integer> domainCodes){

    }
```

In your tests, now you can inject the mocks.

---

If you don't want to edit your source, then you can use reflection to set a private instance variable on an object

```
//Using reflection to set a private field on an object
FieldUtils.writeField(controllerInstance, "domainCodes", new HashMap<>()) ;
```

Comment: We are setting up the domainNameToCode resource via a bean in our configuration so can't use either of these

Comment: @DavidStewart so what I am doing by using `@autowired`, if you are not familier with autowiring concepts please go through the documentation.